# What does "show Callum what he was missing" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I am wondering what "show Callum what he was missing" means in the following sentences:

> ‘I was on my phone,’ I say, ‘and I could see that Callum was with
> Ellie. She’d shared all these pics on Snapchat. There was one of her
> sitting on his lap. And then another one of her kissing him, while she
> held one middle finger up to the camera like she didn’t want anyone to
> take the picture . . . except then she went and shared it for the
> whole world to see, for fuck’s sake.’
>
> Hannah takes a drink from the bottle, breathes out. ‘That must have
> made you feel pretty awful,’ she says. ‘Seeing that. Jeez, social
> media has a lot to answer for.’
>
> ‘Yeah.’ I shrug. ‘It did make me feel a bit . . . shit.’ In case I
> sound like a total stalker I don’t tell her how many times I looked at
> those photos, how I sat there clutching my Sainsbury’s bag and crying
> while I did it. ‘My mates had been saying I should have some fun,’ I
> say. ‘You know, like **show Callum what he was missing**. They kept
> telling me to get myself on some dating apps, but I didn’t want to do
> it at uni, where it was all so incestuous.’
>
> ‘What, apps like Tinder?’
>
> I think she’s trying to show she’s down with the kids. ‘Yeah, but no
> one really uses Tinder any more.’
>
> ‘Sorry,’ she says. ‘I’m ancient, remember. What do I know?’ She says
> it a bit wistfully.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 17

The day before the wedding, after the rehearsal dinner, Hannah and Olivia went out to a cave to talk about Olivia's breakup. Olivia is saying that her ex-boyfriend Callum started dating with Ellie.

In this part, I am wondering what "show Callum what he was missing" means in this context.

Comment: She was advised to go out with other men, to show Callum the fun that he could have been having with her if he hadn't left her.

Comment: The pattern of questions is not constructive to the purpose of the site. First, it’s unnecessary to post multiple paragraphs surrounding the item you need help with, nor extensive explanation of what the book is about or description of a scene or its background. This gives us too much to read. Secondly, it feels like you are asking the community to help you read a long book that is probably too complex to efficiently help you develop your English competence. 1/

Comment: If you go into the site's [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) someone might help you think about better or worse ways to advance your purpose. You can ping me there by @ and I should be able to see it. 2/2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has engaged in a pattern of question-asking that is not constructive to the purpose of the site. I've given my opinion on how they might adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She was advised to go out with other men, to show Callum the fun that he could have been having with her if he hadn't left her. --KB